# How do I remove illegal characters from an NSString?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am parsing a tab seperated list using a NSScanner based upon each line and the tabs. However for some reason the last field in the array (parsed from each row) contains a \r character.

How can I strip this from the NSString that represents the line (or the field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `\r` character is at the end (probably because the file being parsed is CRLF), you can just do something like `[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]`. (You might want to use an explicitly created `'\r'` character set instead if you don't want to strip whitespace as well.)

Comment: I ended up just using a substring, but this is probably the most appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  [+[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  method with NSScanner in your various scanning method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, The \r is part of the line ending for a file created in a windows environment.